# Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: docker, build, pip, amazon-ecr

I am trying to build a django project to push it to an ECR instance but I am having trouble building the project through docker.

Running this command:

```
docker build -t stuffkeep-docker-app .
```

Results in this error and I have not found any way to resolve this yet.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo, django-allauth, django-rest-framework, fcm-django, gcloud, http-ece, jws, py-vapid, pywebpush
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      /tmp/pip-build-env-9x4p5_f7/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:459: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports
      copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/backports/zoneinfo
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/lib
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      lib/zoneinfo_module.c: In function ‘zoneinfo_fromutc’:
      lib/zoneinfo_module.c:600:19: error: ‘_PyLong_One’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘_PyLong_New’?
        600 |             one = _PyLong_One;
            |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
            |                   _PyLong_New
      lib/zoneinfo_module.c:600:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
```

and

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am very aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71712258/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-backports-zoneinfo-which-is-required-to-insta) which has the same error but the poster of that is building for Heroku which I am *not* using and the solutions given are heroku focused.